# How to get path of the process by pid and restart it - c

Tags: c, ubuntu, watchdog

I'm implementing Watchdog (the app starts watchdog) and can't figure out how to restart a process using a process' path.
Edited: How to get path of the process by pid and restart it.
Any help or ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: [exec](https://linux.die.net/man/3/exec) ?

Comment: If I guess correctly what you are maybe trying to do, then your watchdog should probably be the one which starts the process in the first place, so it will have the path and arguments already.

Comment: No, the app starts the Watchdog. Watchdog receives pid and remembering the path of the app to restart it if it failed.

Comment: Why do you want to get the path out of pid? What if the process dies before the watchdog has a chance to retreive the path? Make the process send its own path to the watchdog (and command line arguments too).

Comment: The `pipe trick` : open a pipe & fork a child. If the pipe is closed, the other side is dead. Or, even simpler : just fork& block on wait().

Answer (score 0):

You can run your exe directly by using system Library in C.
System library executes any command that you can execute in Command Prompt or Bash. So use the batch commands to kill and then rerun the program. To rerun you will need to use the full path.

`Windows`

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
  system("taskkill /IM executablename");
  int status = system("executablename");
}
```

`Linux`

```
 int main(){
      system("killall -v executablename");
      int status = system("fullexecutablenameandpath");
    }
```

Comment: That does not restart the process... Also it does not use the process' path.

Comment: I have added details to kill and restart. Your question is not clear.

Comment: I'm not the asker, just wanted to explain the downvote. I think the question is too unclear to be answerable. It might be asking for a shell script even.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I have edited to make it more related. The question was confusing. I have updated the answer so that it helps others who come looking.

Comment: It's not about shell script, but c.

Comment: As said any command that works on the command line, can be passed to system("command"); 
e.g. system("kill -HUP 1"); I can't verify as I don't have any accessible linux system now.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a XY problem. Don't start an app that then starts a watchdog which might then restart the app.

Write a watchdog (or simply use the already existing one form systemd) to start, watch and restart the app. The path and arguements for the app are then simply passed as arguments to the watchdog.

This way the whole thing will actually work.

Comment: If it seems like an XY problem, then post a comment to the question, instead of answer.